# Make the form's background to transparent

Tags: vb.net, transparency, borderless

I made a borderless form and I set my background image (in PNG format) to something like the one shown in the image below. What I want is to make the form's background transparent so that only the circular image is shown. I tried changing the form's `BackColor` to `Transparent` but I'm getting an error saying `Property value is not vald`

[image]

Comment: Does your image have that white background, or the form?

Comment: @aksu, nope. my image is in PNG format and it doesn't have any background.

Comment: Use the designer to set the TransparencyKey and BackColor properties to a pink color.  If that produces a pink fringe around the image then you need to go back to your painting program and give the image a hard edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub
```

*(or)*

Call the SetStyle method of your form in the constructor.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
```

Comment: I tried `Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent` but the form closes and the debugging stopped

Comment: Try  Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent

Answer (score 10):

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

         Me.TransparencyKey = Color.LightBlue
         Me.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If the background color to transparent work, you could set `TransparencyKey` attribute to yur form to make the white color transparent.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TransparencyKey = Color.White 'if this doesn't work you try:
   'Me.TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no `TransparencyKey` in the Me properties, only `Me.AllowTransparency`

Comment: The auto complete thing doesn't show it, did you try my code fully? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
   Public Class Form1
Private _InitialStyle As Integer
<Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure MARGINS
    Public LeftWidth As Integer
    Public RightWidth As Integer
    Public TopHeight As Integer
    Public Buttomheight As Integer
End Structure

<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("dwmapi.dll")>
Public Shared Function DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef pMarinset As MARGINS) As Integer
End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.MainMenuMaster' table. 'You can move, or remove it, as needed.
   Try
        Me.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
        Dim margins As MARGINS = New MARGINS
        margins.LeftWidth = -1
        margins.RightWidth = -1
        margins.TopHeight = -1
        margins.Buttomheight = -1
        Dim result As Integer = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Me.Handle, margins)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Application.Exit()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label1.BackgroundColor = color.FromArgb(25, color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,
set form's properties from designing side

back color=system>active-caption
and set transparency >active-caption

and write following code in to the form constructor or activated event:

```
 SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
 Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

You can also this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEuxm-FV-cU